# Javascript find() array method is returning undefined. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux, state-management

On the click of a button. I am dispatching the id to my resellerSlice so that I can be able to use .find() and select the exact array object that has the same id as my id

```
const handleDetailsModal = (e) => {
 
     setResellersId(e.currentTarget.id)
 
     dispatch(uiAction.toggle())
     dispatch(
         toggleResellers (resellersId)
     )
 
 }
```

On getting to the resellerSlice

```
    const resellerSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'reseller',
        initialState,
        reducers: {
            toggleResellers(state, action) {
                const resellerId = action.payload;
                const clickedReseller = state.resellers?.find((reseller) => reseller.id === resellerId);
    
                console.log(clickedReseller) //returns undefined(this is the problem)
    
              
            }
          
        }
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

I need the const 'clickedReseller' to contain the properties of object that its Id is the same as the 'resellersId', So I can use the object.

Here's my initial state

```
const initialState = [
    {
        resellerName: 'xxxx xxxx',
        id: 1,
        resellerLimits: [
            {
                USD: 700,
                GBP: 200,
                EURO: 990,
            }
        ],
        paymentMethods: [
            'wirePay',
            'flux',
            'bankTransfer'
        ],
        totalTransactions: 0,
        rating: 0,
    },
```

This is what the objects inside the array looks like

Comment: i would  debug the resellerId and state.resellers

Comment: What kind of type does the array `resellers` contain? And did you check if the value `action.payload` arrives properly? And what type is it?

Comment: @GergelyVízvári When I console.log resellerId, I get the value I am expecting. SO I think that part is correct

Comment: Are you sure `state.resellers` is not empty? `find` returns undefined when no values satisfy the condition https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: state.resellers is not empty. Infact is a dummy array I created for my initial state. Let me update the question with the nature of my initial state

Comment: btw use ```(state.resellers || []).find``` instead ```state.resellers?.find``` (or just remove ```?``` if you sure that value cannot be not iterative)

Comment: In `initialState` there is no resellers property...

Comment: @GergelyVízvári I am still getting undefined

Comment: @HaimAbeles Yeah, the payload arrived properly, when I console the resellerId from the slice, I get the value I am expecting

Answer (score 2):

So, I finally figured it out.

My resellerId was actually a string and not an integer.

I discovered this after doing a typeOf() on it.

So instead of using the === comparison operator I used == and it worked out.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the state of your reducer is alreay the `state.resellers` as demonstrated in [the redux toolkit documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#reducers), so you can do directly `state.find(reseller => reseller.id === resellerId)` !

Comment: I also tried this, I kept getting back undefined